# Can I use Ubuntu as a wireless media server which performs all decoding/processing server-side?

Tags: remote-access, media, mediaserver

I want to setup UBUNTU 12.04 desktop as Home media server. I have window 7 netbook and UBUNTU 12.04lts laptop even a samsun galaxy note tablet (android). Two desktop in other room with dualboot win7 and ubuntu. SHARP AQUOS Plasma Tv with Wi-Fi connected.

I want to install ubuntu as media server to stream audio/video files over wi-fi.
Not only this i want this media server to use its own processing power to decode ans stream so that on remote end only file can play without using their own resource.

Is it possible to use ubuntu as media server to stream files without making the remote end to use there own resource. I want only bandwidth of Wi-Fi to be use in this and media center hardware resource.Remote end gadget should use only speaker and screen and not processing power of their own.

Please any suggestion is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a totally "pure" answer to your question (client still performs some processing), you seem to be describing a process called transcoding.

Transcoding involves the server playing a compressed file and sending a decompressed stream to the client. Thus the server does most of the heavy lifting because playing a pure, uncompressed WAV- or MPEG- like signal requires much less computation than would be necessary for a compressed original source such as MP3, Matroska with x264 compression, etc.

There's a few options for UPnP servers that support transcoding on Ubuntu. I like [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org). From what I've read `rygel` looks pretty promising as well. `MediaTomb` and `uShare` are two other fairly popular UPnP servers, but I don't believe they transcode.

---

Hope this helps! I don't know how stringent your requirement is. If you need the client to do absolutely zero processing, this obviously won't work. But you may find this lightens the load enough for your purposes. Good luck.

PS: In the strictest sense izx is correct - the only way (of which I am aware) to perform this with absolutely zero processing at the recipient is as he describes. Pure AV signal just like you could put into a television.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "media server" to perform all processing and only the "screen and speakers" to be used on the remote side, and to do this over wifi, you need to use [**HDMI-over-WiFi**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005LS5WS6).